# jQuery Mobile – Toggle enable and disable state of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a radio button that I would like to be able to enable and disable through jQuery Mobile.

Radio button code:

```
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="option1" />
```

tried:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and

```
$('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled', '');
```

Neither of which seem to be able to toggle the button to enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" id="rdoToggle" value="option1" />
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('enable');
```

[Refer the documnentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/radiobuttons/methods.html) , jQuery and jQuery Mobile are different in this action.

```
$('#rdoToggle').toggle(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('enable');
}, function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('disable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $(elem).prop('propertyname') see more: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

I think checkboxes might be what you're looking for instead:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/checkbox/

Checkboxes are automatically selected and deselected through user clicks, unlike radio buttons that still don't seem to have a convenient way of being deselected after selection.